# ggplot histogram showing extra grey bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

So I'm trying to get this histogram to display by the variable `compage`. Code I'm using is this:

```
hist.wrinko.age <- ggplot(ESSdata.oldage3, aes(wrinco2,fill=compage))
                        + theme(legend.position = "right")
                        + geom_bar(aes(y=..density..), binwidth=1, position="dodge")
                        + labs(x="WRINCO by age group", y = "Density")
                        + scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0, 10, 1)
                          )
```

It works OK, but the histogram looks like this:

[image: histogram]

Basically the legend shows 2 variables, but the histogram shows 3.

I've no idea where the third grey lines are coming from - is there something wrong with my code?

Comment: Hard to say without seeing any data. I tried to reproduce with `diamonds`: `ggplot(subset(diamonds, color %in% c("D", "E")), aes(x = carat, fill=color))` with the rest of your plot commands, but it looks just fine. What does your data look like? `dput(head(ESSdata.oldage3, 20))` would be nice.

Comment: Data looks like this: structure(list(wrinco2 = c(4, 7, 6, 10, 9, 8, 4, 8, 10, 4), rspslvo2 = c(7, 
7, 6, 5, 8, 10, 5, 10, 5, 7), svclvo2 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, NA, 
2, 0, 2), agea = c(27, 33, 53, 40, 36, 77, 20, 51, 49, 86), compage = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("wrinco2", 
"rspslvo2", "svclvo2", "agea", "compage"), row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")

Comment: When I run your code on the data you share, I see no grey bars. Can you share data that reproduces the problem?

Comment: My data is about 43,000 lines, so can't share it all - but it's all in the same structure as the above..

Comment: compage vector should contain 1 or 0. I just checked and the total number of 0 and 1 doesn't sum to total number of lines. Wonder if there are some rogue values in there. How can I check if there are any values in that column that aren't 1 or 0?

Comment: .. but if there were rogue values wouldn't the legend contain more items?

Comment: `table(ESSdata.oldage3$compage, useNA = "always")` should tell you what's there. And yes, that's what is confusing, and also the color. With the default fill color scale, 3 colors should be red, green, blue.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @Gregor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grey bars are added when there is data to plot (x and y values), but the `fill` variable is `NA`.

The easiest way to omit `NA` from your data is the `na.omit` function

```
ggplot(na.omit(ESSdata.oldage3), ...
```